# Windows Explorer requires an extra 4 MB to show volume size as integer GBs?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-explorer

When I create a volume in Disk Management MMC `diskmgmt.msc`, I prefer whole GBs. I noticed that "whole" GBs aren't displayed as integer GBs in Explorer.

For example, when I create a volume of 1024 MB in Disk Management (DM), it's shown as 0.99 GB in Explorer:

> [image: 1]
>
> [image: 2]

However, if I add an extra 4 MB to the volume, it's shown as 1.00 GB:

> [image: 3]
>
> [image: 4]

It's the same for larger volumes:

- 4096 MB = 3.99 GB
- 4100 MB = 4.00 GB
- 4108 MB = 4.01 GB (Correct)
- 131072 MB = 127 GB (Decimal truncated, would've been 127.99 GB)
- 131076 MB = 128 GB

But the volume size in bytes is correct:

> [image: 5]

Tested on Windows XP, Windows 7 (Service Pack 1), Windows 10 (v1803) in VMware. The result is consistent across the 3 Windows versions.

**Why is that?**

Comment: What happens if you create the partition only 1MB larger than it "should" be? Does it have to be *at least* 4MB larger or is there a lower limit?

Comment: @Mokubai It still shows as `(N-1).99 GB` even if it's 3 MB larger than it "should" be, i.e., 4 MB is a lower bound for the extra space.

Comment: Fair enough. I was curious as to whether it was actually 4MB or less. There is actually a [Volume Boot Record](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) (VBR), essentially a partition based version of the disk MBR, but I cannot find any information on how large it or its associated structures should be. It *sounds* like it is just a boot sector and I'd be surprised if it were 4MB...

Comment: @Mokubai Indeed, there used to be a saying that the "exact GB" number in MB was `N*1028 - 4` (instead of `N*1024 + 4`) and I remember verifying it, but I can't verify it again now.

Comment: It still valid  for windows 11. I don't know why.. Microsoft...